# Strand Sort in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, sorting

After reading about [Strand Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand_sort) on Wikipedia and testing the provided Python version, I decided to try my hand at a faster implementation. I've studied the "Time Complexity" page, read [many different approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-python) to mergesort (and borrowed some), tested the code myself with profiler, `line_profiler`, and `timeit`, and I think I've got sped up pretty well.

I'm looking for any ideas on how to optimize this code without changing the sorting algorithm itself or resorting to using Python's `timsort` for any number of elements.

```
def strand_sort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    result = []
    while array:
        i = 0
        sublist = []
        sublist.append(array.pop())
        while i < len(array):
            num = array[i]
            if num > sublist[-1]:
                sublist.append(num)
                del array[i]
            else:
                i = i + 1
        result = merge(list(result), sublist)
    return result

def merge(list_1, list_2):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    merged_list = []
    while i < len(list_1) and j < len(list_2):
        if list_1[i] > list_2[j]:
            merged_list.append(list_2[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            merged_list.append(list_1[i])
            i += 1
    merged_list += list_1[i:]
    merged_list += list_2[j:]
    return merged_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When calling `merge(list(result), sublist)` it is not necessary to create a copy using `list(result)`, because `merge` creates a new list.
- You initialize `sublist` with the last element of `array`. Popping the last element is most efficient, yes, but it means that sorting an already sorted list is not the best case for you. Instead the best case is a rather rare situation where the list is otherwise sorted exept that the smallest item is at the end.
- Using `del array[i]` involves moving all subsequent items one position back. You could avoid the use of `del` by appending to two new lists instead.

Comment: This comment has been well-noted. Popping left ( `array.pop(0)` ) changes the complexity on an already sorted list to be O(1), and the slight decrease in speed is made up by using two lists instead of `del`-ing from one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You're wasting a bit of time instantiating an empty list to instantly append to it with `sublist`. You'd be better off creating `sublist` as a list containing the `array.pop()` element.

```
    sublist = [array.pop()]
```

You could also save time in merge by just calling `len` once at the start. Since these lists aren't modified in the loop there's no need to call it on each iteration.

Stylewise, you could have better names. I know you can't call it a `list`, but `array` isn't quite accurate. Maybe `sortable` or `collection`? More importantly, you don't need to use `num` when your algorithm actually works on characters lexicography.

```
>>> strand_sort("See this can actually still be sorted".split())
['See', 'actually', 'be', 'can', 'sorted', 'still', 'this']
```

This obviously causes a little oddness with capitals being sorted before other letters. But since you're just using the `>` symbol, then this algorithm works on any object that has a function for the operator. I think it's worth noting in a docstring that this can be done, and you can highlight its limitation for sorting strings or explicitly say not to use it for strings even though it's possible.

Comment: Good call about sorting non-number elements. I wrote this for an educational library, but I'll definitely note this.